# How to use loops to add multiple smooth lines to a single ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add different order polynomials with different residual weighting to a single ggplot:

```
p <- ggplot(data = mydf, mapping = aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
# Add Polynomials with Varying Weights
for (i in 1:3){
  for (j in 1:3){
    p <- p+ stat_smooth(method = 'lm', formula= y~poly(x,i), aes(weight= 1/x^j), se=FALSE)
  }
}
print(p)
```

Problem is, the plot only shows the last smooth line only (in this case, third order polynomial, with 1/x^3 weighting.
Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Some sort of lazy evaluation issue?  Have searched on using loops for modifications to objects of class “gg”?

Comment: Yes it is exactly due to the lazy evaluation.  I just dont know how to overcome it.  People have recommended using 'melt' from Reshape package to make the dataframe narrow, but I dont think that solution is applicable here.

Comment: No example data is likely the cause of SO apparent lack of interest in you quuestion. I'm now wondering if this is because the print(p) command is outside the loops? I'm thinking that this would be a case of last layer effectively masking the results of other layers

Comment: I m kind of a newby.  You mean adding hard coded data, or for example, using mtcars example?

Comment: And yes, I did take print(p) inside the loop.  When debugging, it prints every single regression line separately, and the final graph contains only one regression line as well.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am trying to do something very similar and running into the same lazy evaluation issue.

Comment: dgrogan I never did.  Let me know if you do!

Answer (score 0):

If you add a debugging print(p) call inside the loop you will see that the lm calls are producing 3 identical plots for each inner J-value and that the only differences are occurring because of the varying I-the value (degree of polynomial). If the weights are all the same there will be no effect in comparison with the default weights value.

```
mydf <- data.frame(x = 1:20, y=4 +(1:20)^2 + (1:20)^3+rnorm(20,0,5) )
p <- ggplot(data = mydf, mapping = aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
for (i in 1:3){
  for (j in 1:3){
    p <- p+ stat_smooth(method = 'lm', formula= y~poly(x,i), aes(weight= j), se=FALSE)
  print(p) }
}
```

You might have imagined that using `+.gg` would create extra plots but that's not the case.)

Comment: Point taken.  I oversimplified the original code.  It was meant to be weight= 1/x^j.  It was corrected.  Thanks.